# Adding a drop-down to Contact Form plugin

Tags: plugin-contactform

The [GitHub page](https://github.com/craftcms/contact-form) shows how to add additional fields as input fields or checkboxes. But I can't figure out how to add drop-down fields. Is this possible?

```
<select>
  <option value="——" selected="selected">Please select...</option>
  <option name="message[model][]" value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option name="message[model][]" value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option name="message[model][]" value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option name="message[model][]" value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's definitely possible, your HTML is just a little off...

When dealing with a dropdown menu, the `name` attribute should be part of the `select` tag, not each individual option:

```
<select name="message[model]">
  <option value="——" selected="selected">Please select...</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```